# Вылетает приложение при добавлении implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0' в build.gradle (Module: app)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-android

Пытаюсь сделать вход в приложение для Android с FirebaseUI. Но столкнулся с тем, что приложение вылетает при добавлении implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0' в build.gradle (Module: app). Хотя четко пользуюсь руководством с официального сайта (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui).
Вот мой код build.gradle (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.projectmy"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
}
```

Код build.gradle проекта:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?
Ошибки:

```
2020-03-08 15:39:29.203 24771-24836/com.example.studmy E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201)
    at com.example.studmy.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.java:44)
    at com.example.studmy.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:53)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.studmy-KSGzG4XsEGkgCeHblM6fpw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.studmy-KSGzG4XsEGkgCeHblM6fpw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201) 
    at com.example.studmy.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.java:44) 
    at com.example.studmy.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:53) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
2020-03-08 15:39:30.243 24771-24771/com.example.studmy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.studmy, PID: 24771
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201)
    at com.example.studmy.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.java:44)
    at com.example.studmy.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:53)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.studmy-KSGzG4XsEGkgCeHblM6fpw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.studmy-KSGzG4XsEGkgCeHblM6fpw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357) 
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201) 
    at com.example.studmy.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.java:44) 
    at com.example.studmy.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:53) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: стоит наверное посмотреть, что за ошибка

Comment: @keekkenen , добавил текст ошибок, сам не в силах справиться, не понимаю, что именно приводит к вылету приложения при добавлении implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0', буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю Вам надо обновить библиотеки firebase до актуальных, и поддерживать их такими при обновлении хотя бы одной из библиотек.
такое у меня наблюдалось при переходе на androidx

с такой же проблемой столкнулся при использовании com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth на старых сервисах, и обновить, к сожалению, нельзя...